# What happens if the range of gravity extends only 10 light minutes?

Tags: gravity, science-in-society

If the range of gravity abruptly shortens from infinite to mere 10 light minutes, assume no other changes in properties and this effect occurs at no time at all. What happens beyond the Sun's gravitational drop-off?

Comment: I don't think you understand how gravity works....

Comment: Can you elaborate further? For example, how does gravity work at `lim_[x->10-] x` light-minutes?

Comment: @PEMapModder: 2 objects separated by less than 10 light mins apart would obey law of uni gravitation, any more the force drops to zero no worry space-time can take on any bizarre shapes in my world.

Comment: So at `lim_[x->10+] x` light-minutes, you receive no external gravitational forces at all, and at `lim_[x->10-] x` you suddenly get a relatively infinitely greater force? That feels wrong... I mean, in real life, we never encounter any sudden increase in force, only a gradual, even if an enormous slope, increase...

Comment: @PEMapModder: tell that to the nuclear physicist ask them how the weak and strong force works

Comment: @user6760 a nuclear explosion starts with a few atoms having nuclear fission, then the energy propagates to trigger other atoms to have nuclear fission. But right, my way of comparison is probably wrong.

Comment: @PEMapModder: my apology I meant to ask you to compare the range of strong and weak nuclear forces.

Comment: Worldbuilders I know this is a suicide but if 2 bodies are far enough in a close system the gap of space inbetween will be absolutely flat or simply if there is no mass around in the region of space do time still flow?

Comment: @user6760: In response to your last question, it falls under theoretical physics, not world building. While it is known that the spacial dimensions cannot exist without time, it is unknown if time can still exist without space. You have ghastly modified one aspect of the spacetime continuum. It is highly debatable even between elite physicists what effect(s) it would have on other aspects of the spacetime fabric of the universe. In one way, you have shredded the universe into infinite number of small _island universes_, completely detached from one another.

Comment: i don't really think that true [tag:science] answer is possible, as physics doesn't really know any abruptly ending fields. Except for shielding, of course, but that requires physical barrier. Changes to the way world  works would need to be great for this to happen.

Comment: @Mołot But the strong nuclear force does. A conceptual answer is possible, this is only hypothetical after all. See the answers below.

Comment: @a4android it doesn't end abruptly. It smoothly, if fast, goes below observability threshold. See [this chart](http://webs.mn.catholic.edu.au/physics/emery/assets/9_5_op21.gif).

Comment: @Mołot. Very interesting, but at distances in units of 10^-15 m, that's close enough to ending abruptly even it falls smoothly and fast. This could easily describe this hypothetically short-range gravity's limit. Any idea that it would fall to zero in zero distance is amusing to say the least.

Comment: Uncertainty principle governs why massive boson are short range while massless one such as photon can have unlimited range, so long the debate is healthy I don't mind getting down votes at all. (just kept it within a cap of 0)

Answer (score 8):

### Solar systems don't even form.

Ten light-minutes is barely more than the radius of Earth's orbit around the sun.  Assuming gravitational effects have always been short-to-medium-range phenomena no celestial body large enough to initiate stellar fusion would ever form.  The accumulation of matter in gravity wells from the supposed "initial condition" of a baryonic soup depends on the attraction of gravity accumulating over much larger distances than this.

Answer (score 5):

## 1- The Universe Would Be Cold ... And Dead

Considering that solar systems have planets at distances of several dozen light minutes (Earth is at 8:20 while Jupiter is at more than 40 light minutes from the sun), the solar systems, as know them, would never form. You might think that Earth-like terrestrial planets would still form around stars, but that would be impossible. Read ahead.

Galaxies have lengths of dozens of thousands of light *years*. Limiting gravity to mere minutes range would mean that galaxies never form at all. Without going into lengthy details, let it suffice to say that supermassive blackholes of galactic centers never form at all, putting galaxies out of the picture completely.

Which means that after the Big Bang, universe would go on to expand at nearly the speed of light. Once the individual particles are more than 10 light minutes away from one another, there would be no way for them to ever reunite.

The universe would just be composed of infinitely small, infinite number of sub-atomic particles, moving away from one another at 99.999% the speed of light. It would be a dark, cold, dead universe.

## 2- If It Was Thus, You Would Never Get To Ask This Question

This should be self-evident.

Comment: #2 says it all that's why there is no #3